# Visual Studio Code Account Not Loading

Tags: visual-studio-code

My vscode account won't load, this means: emmet stops working, I can't use github remote repositories(I use my github account), Intellisense doesn't work and my extensions don't work. Also, when I click accounts button it just shows loading but never loads. Could You Please Help Me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Manjaro, like me, you may want to try to install the official release visual-studio-code-bin from AUR.  If you use the FOSS compiled versions it doesn't include some of the proprietary sync features from microsoft.  Hope that helps.

Comment: What's manjaro? I don't know what that is.

Comment: Sorry about that.  My answer may be completely unrelated.  It's a linux distribution.  I ran into the same issue and aside from installing an alternative that was the only way I could get the sync features to work.  I imagine if you are using some other version of linux the issue would be the same.